# Training, validation and test set. How to use the test set in R with LDA()

Tags: statistics, linear-programming, machine-learning, programming

I am new in machine learning and have some problems with the final step of my exercise. I have a training, validation and test set. The test set is the set I have to use at the final step, but I am not entirely sure how.
First I shall tell what I have been doing.

I am busy with some exercises about fitting different models using lda() and knn(). Eventually from all the models I choose the one which performed the best. It looks like this:

> lda.fit = lda(Y~Var1+Var2+Var3+Var4, data=training)
>
> pred = predict(lda.fit, newdata=validation)

Now the part where I am stuck: Pick the best performing model on the validation set, describe it and give the performance of the model on the test set.

So, the model above is my best performing model. I know I have to use the test set to avoid overfitting, but I am not entirely sure where I have to put the test data. Is it like this?

> lda.fit2 = lda(Y~Var1+Var2+Var3+Var4, data=validation)
>
> pred = predict(lda.fit2, newdata=test)

This is what I thought the solution is. Is there someone who can give me an confirmation or correct me?

Comment: Most people on this site may not even know that your lda probably stands for *Latent Dirichlet Allocation*, and you may do better asking such questions on the Cross-Validation site.  There you may be told that having chosen and tuned your model based on the training and validation data as you have done, you fit it on the combination of training and validation data (not just the validation), and use that to predict classifications on the test data as you have done, and then compare these predictions with the true classifications of the test data to give measures of out-of-sample accuracy etc.

Comment: Alright thank you. I think I understand what to do now.